# cordova-plugin-inappbrowser won't open system browser in IOS when using Phonegap Build

Tags: phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I'm trying to get links in a Phonegap app to open the system browser but recently they stopped working when using Phonegap build.  They work if I build the app locally and put it on my phone, but now when the app is built using Phonegap build. I'm including it in my config file like this:

I also have the following code in my deviceready listener:

```
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    console.log("Device is ready!");
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
});
```

And finally, here's an example of what my links look like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_system">Dashboard</a>
```

I've whitelisted the urls that I would like to open.  The strange thing is that if I leave my app, the browser opens and goes to the url.  It appears that I must exit the app to get the link to trigger.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: i've had this problem before. if you build through xcode and try to trigger the url link, does the console have any output on it?